# Why my 4WD Bluetooth car run so slow

Tags: bluetooth

[image]
Code

```
/*Arduino Bluetooth Controlled Car
 *  * Created by Glen Tech 
 * https://www.youtube.com/glentech
  */

#include <AFMotor.h>

//initial motors pin
AF_DCMotor motor1(1); 
AF_DCMotor motor2(2); 
AF_DCMotor motor3(3);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4);

char command; 

void setup() 
{       
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Set the baud rate to your Bluetooth module.
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
    command = Serial.read(); 
    Stop(); //initialize with motors stoped
    //Change pin mode only if new command is different from previous.   
    //Serial.println(command);
    switch(command){
    case 'F':  
      forward();
      break;
    case 'B':  
       back();
      break;
    case 'L':  
      left();
      break;
    case 'R':
      right();
      break;
    }
  } 
}

void forward()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor2.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor2.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor3.setSpeed(1000);//Define maximum velocity
  motor3.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(1000);//Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
}

void back()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor2.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor2.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor3.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor3.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(1000); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
}

void left()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor2.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor2.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor3.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor3.run(FORWARD);  //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(FORWARD);  //rotate the motor clockwise
}

void right()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor1.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor2.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor2.run(FORWARD); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor3.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor3.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
  motor4.setSpeed(255); //Define maximum velocity
  motor4.run(BACKWARD); //rotate the motor anti-clockwise
} 

void Stop()
{
  motor1.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor1.run(RELEASE); //stop the motor when release the button
  motor2.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor2.run(RELEASE); //rotate the motor clockwise
  motor3.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor3.run(RELEASE); //stop the motor when release the button
  motor4.setSpeed(0); //Define minimum velocity
  motor4.run(RELEASE); //stop the motor when release the button
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please put your code in a code block (by adding 4 spaces before each line of code) to make it more readable. Also, add a clear description in your post about your hardware, the problem you are trying to solve and what you already tried. A link to youtube is not sufficient. What battery are you using for your project?

Comment: Can you measure the battery voltage when motors is ON?

Comment: What battery are you using? A 9V block batteries (like pictured) can't supply enough current to properly run a motor.

Comment: A photo of your actual hardware would also be helpful.

Comment: Move the `stop()` to `setup()`, and add some `delay()` in your `loop()`. Your loop is too busy and constantly stop and setting the direction again and again. Also introduce a status that holds the current direction status, if the command is the same as current direction status, skip the `switch` setup section, it only need when the command is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find issue in your code that I'm convinced is your problem. Without seeing your datasheet for the motor, I would bet your issue is one of two things:

1) A 9V battery is low-current relative to most batteries I've used for powering any decent DC motors. Do you have access to a better current source you could try?

2) Every motor has a trade-off in torque vs max-speed, dictated by the internal gear-ratio. Depending on the motor type, it may not have the torque to accelerate the vehicle to a significant speed.